# SQL Server - Select column to update based on another column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Had a small doubt.

I have 2 tables with the following structures

**Status table**

```
S_ID | filename | addresscode | Total_Count | Vendor_Count | Co_Count | Cust_Count | Completion_Date
```

**Records table**

```
R_ID | filename | addresscode | Date | From | To | Quantity
```

I am writing a trigger which updates the value of Status stable based on the values which are inserted in the Records table. I want the following to happen (where inserted tale is i and status table is f):

Update status table

- If i.From = 'Vendor' then SET Vendor_Count = f.Vendor_Count - i.Quantity
- If i.From = 'Co' then SET Co_Count = f.Co_Count - i.Quantity
- If i.From = 'Cust' then SET Cust_Count = f.Cust_Count - i.Quantity
- If i.To = 'Vendor' then SET Vendor_Count = f.Vendor_Count + i.Quantity
- If i.To = 'Co' then SET Co_Count = f.Co_Count + i.Quantity
- If i.To = 'Cust' then SET Cust_Count = f.Cust_Count + i.Quantity

I understand that I will have to use `Case`, but am not able formulate the right syntax. Please help.

Also had another (bonus) small query if possible to answer - How should I do this ->  I want to update the status table as

- IF i.To = 'Cust' & IF (f.cust_count + i.quantity == f.total_count) SET Completion_Date = i.Date

Comment: Ouch I hope those aren't your real column and table names. Using reserved words is painful to work with. Also, why are you storing calculated values like this? In general it is not a good approach to store calculated values because they can (and will) get out of synch at some point. A computed column or calculating during retrieval would be much better.

Comment: Those are not my real column and table names :) - Can you please provide some reference to what is a computed column?I wasn't using during retrieval as I would've needed joins and initially I wasn't comfortable with them and thought it would get too complex for me. But will look into calculating during retrieval (using joins) once. Thanks!

Comment: If you use pretty much any search engine for the term "sql server computed column" you will find this as the very first result. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx It comes from books online (BOL), you should become familiar with it as it is the documentation for sql server.

Comment: ok thank you! Sorry for the laziness '*embarrassed*'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming i.From <> i.To the following `CASE`s give you the required values

```
CASE 
    WHEN i.From = 'Vendor' THEN Vendor_Count - i.Quantity 
    WHEN i.To = 'Vendor' THEN Vendor_Count + i.Quantity 
    ELSE Vendor_Count 
END,
CASE 
    WHEN i.From = 'Co' THEN Co_Count - i.Quantity 
    WHEN i.To = 'Co' THEN Co_Count + i.Quantity 
    ELSE Co_Count 
END,
CASE 
    WHEN i.From = 'Cust' THEN Cust_Count - i.Quantity 
    WHEN i.To = 'Cust' THEN Cust_Count + i.Quantity 
    ELSE Cust_Count 
END
```

Bonus:

```
CASE 
    WHEN i.To = 'Cust' & IF (f.cust_count + i.quantity == f.total_count) THEN i.Date 
    ELSE Completion_Date
END
```

Comment: Thanks Caleth. I am getting `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.` and `Incorrect syntax near '='` though

Comment: Is this fine: `WHEN i.To = 'Cust' AND (f.Cust_Count + i.Quantity) = f.Total_Count THEN i.Dispatch_Date` ?